# Doing a tail -f on a text file over sshfs not working. Why?

Tags: tail, sshfs

I successfully mounted a local folder against a remote ssh host.

I now wanted to do a `tail -500f my_text_file` but it's not working very well. Although it does open tail and shows me the file contents, the `-f` part is definitely not working. It must have something to do with `sshfs`. When I do a regular ssh connection it works wonderfully.

Any pointers on how to fix this? I'm using the sshfs version one gets when doing a `sudo apt install sshfs` in Ubuntu.

Comment: Does running `tail` with `---disable-inotify` [sic] make any difference? Does tail give you any warnings? Inotify that tail should be using by default is not supported by sshfs.

Comment: Regardless of whether that helps though, you can try to simulate the command with something like `while true; do clear; tail -500 my_text_file; sleep 1; done`

Answer (score 9):

`tail -f` tries to use a file change notification mechanism ([inotify](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify)). SSHFS, like any other [FUSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace) filesystem, does not support this mechanism. Normally `tail` should discover this on its own. If that doesn't work, you can use the undocumented option `---disable-inotify` (starting with three dashes, because it's an undocumented option) to force the use of polling mode which works on any filesystem.

```
tail ---disable-inotify -n 500 -f my_text_file
```

Answer (score 2):

`sshfs` is using `sftp` protocol to list and transfer files and in the `sftp` protocol (at least as it is implemented in OpenSSH), there is no possibility to notify your local `tail` about updates of the remote file.

As @vovick proposed, you can workaround that using various approaches, for example using polling. Or better way, run the `tail` directly on the remote server (unless it is `sftp`-only).